# Check if record exists in SQL query in a different table if so dont show result

Tags: php, sql

I currently have two tables - `opportunities` & `applications`

Basically I am wondering the best way in my query below to check the applications table and check if the user has already made an application request. If the column `user_id` in applications = '$userID' and `opportunity_id` = `o.id` and `status` ! = 2 - then show the results?

Is there a way to do it via SQLQuery rather than php?

```
SELECT * FROM opportunities o
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.owner_id = o.owner_id
WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(o.languages,'$user->languages')
OR o.opportunity_sales_methods IN ($user->sellingmethods)
OR o.opportunity_our_industry IN ($user->want2sell)
) OR o.opportunity_seller_type LIKE '%$user->sellertype%'
GROUP BY o.id
```

Comment: What exactly does not work with the given query?

Comment: It does work, i am just asking for the best way to also check the applications table and see if the user has already made an application

Comment: should be a JOIN if you want to show the results matching in the two tables. Left join is to show ALL the results in table A and matching or NULL from table B.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea

```
select c1, c2, c3
from t1
where not exists (select t2.c5 from t2 where t1.c4 = t2.c5)
```

you will need to apply this to your tables and fields. You will not need to `group by id`, since it is a `primary key`, therefore `unique`.